# Zend: How to populate data to checkboxes?

Tags: php, zend-framework, checkbox, populate

I am working on zend. I have a form with some checkboxes. I want to get data from database and populate this data to this form. If '1' is stored in table field then tick the check box otherwise leave it alone. In textboxes and dropdowns, data is easily populated but how to check a checkbox in action.

I am creating checkboxes and textboxes elements like this in form.php:

```
// Person name
$person = $this->CreateElement('text', 'name');
$person->setLabel('Name');
$elements[] = $person;    

// Organization name
$person = $this->CreateElement('text', 'organization');
$person->setLabel('Organization');
$elements[] = $person;       

// isAdmin Checkbox
$isAdmin = $this->CreateElement('checkbox', 'isAdmin');
$isAdmin->setLabel('Admin');
$elements[] = $isAdmin;

$this->addElements($elements);
$this->setElementDecorators(array('ViewHelper'));

// set form decorator (what script will render the form)
$this->setDecorators(array(array('ViewScript' , array('viewScript' => 'organization/accessroles-form.phtml'))));
```

How I render a form:

```
<form name="myform" action="<?= $this->element->getAction() ?>" method="<?= $this->element->getMethod() ?>" id="accessrolesform">

<table align="center" width="100%" border="0"><tbody>

<tr>
    <td><?= $this->element->name ?></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td><?= $this->element->organization ?></td>
</tr>


<tr>
    <td><?= $this->element->isAdmin ?></td>
</tr>

</table>
</form>
```

And populating data like this (for example):

```
// Prepare data to populate
$data['name'] = 'Naveed';
$data['organization'] = 'ABC';
$data['isAdmin'] = '1';

// Populate editable data
$this->view->form->populate( $data );
```

It is populating data in textboxes but not checking the checkbox? Any idea that how to check a checkbox from action?

Thanks

Comment: maybe there is something in the decorate.. try to show the html code of such rendered form

Comment: @Gordon: hahaha. You know how I use SO. I am working on a project. When I am assigned some tasks then I workout about them and post some issues on SO which I feel difficult. When I meet the date to perform that task then I read the answers again and try to implement. If an answer helps me then I accept that answer. Therefore I take time to accept an answer :)

Comment: Oh. It started working with above code in my question. I think there was problem with my database data. Anyway sorry for confusion. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the manual:

> By default, the checked value is '1',
>   and the unchecked value '0'. You can
>   specify the values to use using the
>   setCheckedValue()  and
>   setUncheckedValue() accessors,
>   respectively. Additionally, setting
>   the value sets the checked property of
>   the checkbox. You can query this using
>   isChecked() or simply accessing the
>   property. Using the setChecked($flag)
>   method will both set the state of the
>   flag as well as set the appropriate
>   checked or unchecked value in the
>   element. Please use this method when
>   setting the checked state of a
>   checkbox element to ensure the value
>   is set properly.

```
$checkboxElement->setChecked(true);
```

will set the value of the checkbox to 'checked="checked" with a value of "1".

Answer (score 0):

or use $

```
data['isAdmin'] = 1; // NOT string
```